# press a button on external site with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

is there a way to press a button on external site with javascript and/or jquery? Like I open a new window like this:

```
windowObjectReference = window.open("http://some_site.html","name");
```

Then I want to press a button on this site. Something like this:

```
windowObjectReference.button.click();
```

Or:

```
name.button.click();
```

Answer (score 5):

It would be a huge security violation if a browser would let you do that from the script placed on your own website.

So, **no, this cannot be done, and should not be possible**.

But...

If both sites belong to you (you have access to their code), you can **pass a parameter** (eg. as a hash within URL), then the target website may read it and fire the event you mentioned (`name.button.click()`).

Comment: if the second site belongs to you, you wouldn't be doing that in first place, and `window.open` would give you the other window object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.open so no needs for messing up with the hash.

Comment: @greut: If both sites belong to you and they have different domains, then do you really still have access to the content of the window? The question was about _external site_, which I understand as something outside of the domain.

Comment: I know I can access the same domain with window.open(), but the question was about different domains. So thanks for the hash suggestion, I'll try it out.

Comment: @Tadeck indeed, it didn't think about the two of them being on different domains.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with JavaScript from a webpage.
You can do it from browser extension though.

Comment: Thanks, any particular browser and extension you have in mind? I suppose Firefox.

Comment: Pretty much any browser. I use "Blank Canvas Script Handler" in Chrome, Opera has support for user scripts out of the box, Firefox requires a plugin called GreaseMonkey.

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**NO !**

For security reasons. This kind of attack is called [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)! and it was used on [Twitter](http://shiflett.org/blog/2009/feb/twitter-dont-click-exploit).

Comment: I didn't realize that, never heard of clickjacking, name sounds funny though:)

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to press a button on external site with javascript
>   and/or jquery?

I know that I'm late at party but YES, Unfortunately it is and is a quite simple way.

1. make a div on your page (ex. #externalDiv);
2. set CSS attribute to hidden and display to none;
3. use (simple way) jQuery method .load() or make your own JS method using XMLHttpRequest();
4. load external page on your page;
5. click on button you wish

   $('#externalDiv').load('http://www.externalPage.com', function(){$('#externalPageButtonId').click();});

Can not doge by something if you don't know how it's work :)

Comment: That would ONLY work it externalpage.com supported CORS and allowed your site to load it

Comment: Indeed. CORS was accepted by W3C in January 2014. But if you check my answer date you will observe that is January 2014 :). At that moment, the browsers have not fully implemented Access Control Requests and Access Control Responses. Today click event can be fired external with Selenium, for example, or by parsing hrefs and curl its...

Comment: When jQuery came out, CORS was available to all browsers. Chrome3, fx3.5, saf4, ie8

Comment: CORS has been around fully since 2010 or so

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to do so because of SOP. Any [trick to force user to perform click on your behalf](http://podlipensky.com/2012/07/clickjacking-explained/) will be considered as clickjacking attack and could lead to bad consequences.